# Fullcalendar TimeSlot and ScrollTime

Tags: fullcalendar

For a project in which I need a calendar to advanced functions and relatively simple, I chose FullCalendar, which is really convenient and easy.

My only problem is that I try to change the hours displayed in agendaWeek and agendaDay views, which are by default from 06h to 17h. I need to put it from 07h to 22h.

I've watched the BusinessHours setting but without success. scrollTime lets you change the start time of the schedule, but it only grows up to 18h. There certainly has something on the side of ViewObject but I do not know at all how to modify.

Thank you in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

have you set

```
.fullCalendar({
    minTime: "07:00:00",
    maxTime: "22:00:00",
})
```

also may want to set slotDuration

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's hard for me to speak in English because I usually speak French and I may not be properly explained.

min and max time does not match what I want because they limit access to the calendar before 7 am and after 22h. I would like to continue to access other hours with scrollbars. But having the hours between 7 and 22 displayed directly without the need to scroll.

Basically, the goal would be to expand the Calendar vision area

Comment: if you want to expand the area, then make the container larger or set the height in the option when creating fullCalendar.  To have it scroll to a specific time of day, set scrollTime option.  The documentation is very good.